# email validation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, email-validation

is this javascript function (checkValidity) correct?

```
function checkTextBox(textBox)
{
   if (!checkValidity(textBox.getValue()))
       displayError("Error title", "Error message", textBox);
       textBox.focus();
}

function checkValidity(e) 
{
    var email;
    email = "/^[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-z]{2,}$/i";

    if (!e.match(email)){
            return false;
    else
            return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** All the answers appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: basically, the answers to this question should learn you two things: 
 1) many people disagree how to implement it
 2) the solution seems extraordinarily complex for something so ubiquitous...it probably means the specification for email addresses is broken :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E-mail address are defined in [RFC 5322, § 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4). The relevant non-terminal is `addr-spec`. The definition turns out to be somewhat squirelly, due to both the complications of domain specifications and supporting old, obsolete forms. However, you can do an over-approximation for most forms with:

```
^[-0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.]+@[-0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.]+
```

Notice that there are a very large number of legal characters. Most reg-exs get the list wrong. Yes, all those characters are legal in an e-mail address.

This regex will not match some very uncommon used forms like `"noodle soup @ 9"@[what the.example.com]` -- which is a legal e-mail address!

Comment: This form seems to work fine but it does not require the top-level domain. Allowing name@email without any .com or otherwise. What would I need to add to account for that?

Comment: Perhaps you want to ensure at least one dot? Add `\.[-0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.]+` to the end! If you want to ignore internationalized top-level domains, you could simplify that to just adding `\.[A-Za-z]+`

Comment: I'm getting an 'Unrecognized escape sequence' in Visual Studio 2012 on the **dot** after \  

`[RegularExpression("^[-0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~.]+@[-0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~.]\.[-0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~.]{2,4}+", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email")]` 
Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: I'm not sure about it - use '\\' instead of '\'.

Answer (score 3):

```
function isValidEmail($email)
{
    return eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email);
};

if(isValidEmail("name@yahoo.com"))
{
  echo "valid";
}
else
{
   echo "aaa";
};
```

Comment: Who thought you to put `;` after function declarations and if statements?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that regex is not that fit for the purpose. [Have a look at this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) instead (though I can't guarantee it's validity).
Also, regarding the script itself, why are you not checking like this:

```
function checkEmailValidity(e) {
  return e.match("some validating regex");
}
```

It seems like a faster, more consise, and more readable solution.

**EDIT:**
It's worth noting, that it's almost impossible to write a regex that can detect any valid email address. Therefore, you might be better off with trying to make some validation algorithm, instead of a regex, as valid email adresses may be very, very complex.

Consider this code:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    if (typeof email != "string") return false;
    email = email.split("@");
    email[1] = email[1].split(".");
    if (
        email.length !== 2 ||
        email[1].length < 2 ||
        !email[1].hasValues(String)
    ) return false;
    return true;
}

// Checks whether each key in an array has a value, and (optionally) if they match a given contructor (object type).
// I.e.: myArray.hasValues(String) // checks whether all elements in myArray has a value, a nonempty string.
Array.prototype.hasValues = function(assumedConstructor) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (!this[i]) return false;
        if (assumedConstructor && this[i].constructor != assumedConstructor) return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

It works this way:

1. First checking if the string contains one `@`, and only one
2. Checks that the part after the `@` has at least one `.`
3. Checks that there is some characters between each of the possible `.`'s.

It will still be easy to forge a fake email address, but this way we ensure that it's at least *somehow* properly formatted. The only gotcha that I can think of, is `@`'s inside comments, which should be perfectly legal according to the RFC's, but this code will treat it as an error.
Normal internet users, which have normal email adresses, will not fail this. So how much it actually matters is up to you to decide ;)

The best solution, if one is available, is to put the address into some built-in method, that somehow checks for validity by trying to use the email address.

Comment: The regex in the referenced article is wrong - and the author simply claims his definition of e-mail addresses is fine - only it is defined by RFC, and he is wrong.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the reference. I normally don't do regexes, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

No. It assumes that an email address can contain only one `@`. I would suggest reading [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx).

You probably also meant `\.` instead of `.`.

Comment: Addresses can't contain more than one @ unless they're using an obsolete form.

Comment: @Thom Not true.  Read the RFC.

Comment: Actually, the RFC allows @ inside a quoted-string which can come before the @ that separates the local-part from the domain.  So "party@dougs"@example.com is a valid e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: I am sure it takes care of all kinds of email validation.

```
function checkEmail(email)
{   
    if(/^([a-z]([a-z]|\d|\+|-|\.)*):(\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?((\[(|(v[\da-f]{1,}\.(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~)|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)+))\])|((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=])*)(:\d*)?)(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*|(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)|((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)){0})(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(email)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: I think that you can safely ignore addresses in certain deprecated formats that haven't been used in decades.

Comment: RFC 5322 § 3.4.1 defines the address specification for e-mail. It doesn't allow the range of characters listed here. Specifically, it doesn't support non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex corresponding to the RFC, also excluding the obsolete forms. I've broken it up into components so that it will be easy to read:

```
IDENT = [a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
TEXT = [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+

EMAIL = TEXT(?:\.TEXT)*@IDENT(?:\.IDENT)+
```

(Note: case insensitive.)

This won't match email addresses that use the quoted form before the @ or the bracketed form after it, but while those forms are valid, they're hardly ever seen nowadays outside of examples, and they significantly complicate the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Validating an email address is *very difficult*.  It's not even worth validating on the client-side, other than very basic checking for `@` and `.` characters.

[Section 3.4.1 of RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) elaborates on the immense variety of legal characters, and you'll see that creating a bullet-proof regex is going to be nearly impossible.

I ended up giving up on validating because I would get occasional complaints from users saying their crazy email address does not work.  So, from now on I just attempt to send the email and hope it gets delivered.  If it fails to send, then I tell the user their e-mail address is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

While doing a couple of searches I came across this. Its based on RFC 2822

http://snipplr.com/view/20981/

Answer (score 0):

this is an e-mail validation function `with validateEmail('e-mail')

```
      function validateEmail(id) {
let emailField = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
let email = emailField.value.trim();

if (email === "") {
    errors.push(`the field ${id} is required.`);
} else {
    let emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
        errors.push(`message ${id}.`);
    }
}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).